# Is there a word or phrase for Walking slowly while tracing the surrounding with hands?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So the scene goes like this, **she comes of the dark and is unable to see things at once. So she slowly walks while tracing the surrounding with her hands**.

Is there a exclusive word for such an act?

Answer (score 2):

**feel one's way** idiom

> 1: to move forward carefully by using one's hands to feel anything in
> the way
> *He felt his way through the darkened room.*
>
> [2: to move toward a goal very slowly and carefully
> *In the early days of the project they were just feeling their way (along), trying not to make mistakes.*] [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feel%20one%27s%20way#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20to%20move%20forward%20carefully,trying%20not%20to%20make%20mistakes.)

> She made her way down the stairs, **feeling her way** quietly in the dark.
> [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Voices_of_Southeast_Asia/Li_fBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22feeling%20her%20way%22&pg=PA168&printsec=frontcover).

> She reached in front of her, **feeling her way** along the first wall,
> turning left around a corner. Two more false starts, and she found
> herself turning left ... [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Play_Dead/I28uDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22feeling%20her%20way%22&pg=PT48&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: **feeling her way though the darkness** that suits the scene perfectly. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

She was literally ***groping in the dark***.

TFD(idioms):

> ***[grope in the dark](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/groping+in+the+dark)***
>
> 1. Literally, to feel about without the use of one's eyes, as due to blindness or an absence of light.
>    I was groping in the dark down in
>    this basement for ten minutes before I could find a light switch.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.